# django v1.6 - using cycle tag twice in a single loop

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, cycle

I am using django version 1.6. I have a for loop that requires {% cycle %} template tag to assign a different value to each loop, one is at a class level and another at image source.

```
{% for item in items %}
   <article class={% cycle '"entry style-grid style-hero"' '"entry style"' ... %}>
   .... some more code ...
   <img src={% cycle '"/static/file.png/"' '"/static/file1.png/"' %}>
{% endfror %}
```

The first cycle loop seems to work fine but the second cycle loop does not work. The html source shows the whole cycle block including the tags for the second one.

I have also used {% load cycle from future %} which is a new feature in 1.6 version but it is still not working.

Not sure how to get it to work.

EDIT:

```
{% for item in items %}
            <article class={% cycle '"entry style-grid style-hero hero-sm-largest type-post col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' '"entry style-grid style-hero type-post col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' '"entry style-grid style-hero type-post col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' '"entry style-grid style-hero type-post col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' '"entry style-grid style-hero type-post col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' '"entry style-grid style-hero type-post col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' '"entry style-grid style-hero type-post col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' '"entry style-grid style-hero type-post col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' '"entry style-grid style-hero type-post col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' '"entry style-grid style-hero type-post col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' '"entry style-grid style-hero type-post col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 colheight-sm-1 colheight-md-2 colheight-lg-2 colheight-xl-2"' %}>

                <div class="ribbon ribbon-pulled ribbon-small ribbon-highlight">
                    <a href="{{item.slug}}">{{ item.name}} </a>
                    <a href="{{item.slug}}"><img src="{{ item.country}}" alt="{{item.country}}" /></a>
                </div>

                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="{{item.slug}}">{{item.name}}</a> </h3>
                    <div class="entry-meta">
                        <span class="entry-date"><a href="{{item.slug}}">
                        {{item.profession}}</a></span>
                    </div>
                </header>

                <figure class="entry-thumbnail">

                    <a href="{{item.slug}}" class="overlay overlay-primary"></a>

                    <!-- to disable lazy loading, remove data-src and data-src-retina -->


                         <img src={% cycle '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture}}" alt="{{item.name}}"' 
                         '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}"' 
                         '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}"' 
                         '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}"' 
                         '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}"' 
                         '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}"' 
                         '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}"' 
                         '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}"' 
                         '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}"' 
                         '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}"' 
                         '"/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}"'  %}>

                    <noscript>
                        <img src="/media/{{item.picture}}" alt="">
                    </noscript>

                </figure>
            </article>
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the whole content of the `{% for %}` loop?  Also there is a syntax error (`{% endfror %}` instead of `{% endfor %}`).

Comment: @catavaran sure I will paste it above. Sorry that was a typo here but on the html page it is correct.

Comment: @catavaran hey just pasted it above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% cycle %}` template tag can't be multi-line.  Join in to the single line.

But anyway your code will not work - `{{ variable }}` will not be expanded in the `{% cycle %}` tag.  You should use `{% if %}` tag here:

```
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"11" %}
   <img src="/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture}}"
           data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture}}" alt="{{item.name}}">
{% else %}
   <img src="/static/placeholder.gif" data-src="/media/{{item.picture_small}}"
           data-src-retina="/media/{{item.picture_small}}" alt="{{item.name}}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. The problem though is that the values inside the tags is not rendering. i.e. /media/{{item.picture_small}} does not render the actual location and file name. The html source just prints as is

Comment: Note the `{% if %}` option in the answer.

Comment: thanks for your response. I had posted my comment without refreshing the screen. It turns out you had already given an answer for the next problem I encountered. You were thorough with this one Sir. Thank you very much.